# iPhone 4 - Verification Required

Tags: applications, iphone, ios-appstore

I've been using the App Store through my Apple ID for a while and everything has been normal.

Now, all of the sudden, when I want to update an app or to download a free app *after putting my password* a pop-up message appears entitled:

> Verification Required

asking me to verify my payment info. In my phone's account settings, the payment information is set to NONE since ever, still there's a red message up saying:

> You must verify your payment info before you make purchases.

The thing is, I don't have any payment info, that is why I only use free apps. What to do?

Comment: I had this a few times also, i fixed it by downloading another free app that i haven't downloaded before. I had to verify my payment info also, but at that time the option "none" was possible

Comment: @pkamp If you search for similar questions to edit, please also consider flagging/closing duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Select Verify Payment Info, and under Credit Card, just choose None. If this doesn't work, close the App Store and go to Settings > App Store > Tap on your Email > View Apple ID > Payment Information > None.

This should fix the issue.